# How to perform regression analysis? (Including assumptions)

Tags: regression

As far as I know first I have to standardize the variables. Then I have to check whether they are normal or not, then I should check whether there is multicolinearity. Then I perform the make regression and check whether the residuals are randomly distributed or not.

Is there anything I am missing or have wrong?

Comment: For more information, [search our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=regression%20diagnostics): there are hundreds of answers addressing variations of this question.

Comment: @whuber, There were no helpful results.

Comment: Right: you checked all 133 results in the last 17 minutes. What's the matter with the duplicate? What else are you looking for?

Comment: @whuber, no. I have checked only the most 5-10 relevant results. they were not much related with my question. the lower ones tend to be unrelated at all.

Comment: I went through them all (quickly) and found these may be worth looking at: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28688, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51046, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57549, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17673, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41194, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28688, and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32600 (the dup). Plenty of others are relevant but need some imagination to apply; for instance, many of the questions on logistic regression contain useful information.

Answer (score 2):

You do *not* have to standardize the variables; you do *not* have to check them for normality. You *should* check for collinearity. The *residuals* should be normally distributed and not related to the independent variables.

Beyond that there is a whole lot to do. There is the whole issue of model selection, for one. You need to check for outliers. There is more, too.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to make assumptions about the distribution of the predictors. If a predictor is heavily skewed towards higher values, you may need to transform it though.

Watch out for multicolinearity (hint: VIF). Always make sure your residuals are normally distributed, if they're not - do something. Transforms of the predictors can be worth trying out.

EDIT: Removed first line of post (wrong info). Check the later answers for information regarding standardization of the predictors.

Comment: What software standardizes the predictors for you? `R` does not, `SAS` does not and I am pretty sure `SPSS` does not. At least, not by default.  Nor is it necessary to do so (although some people think it is a good idea).  Also, condition indexes are a better method for collinearity than VIFs are.

Comment: That is debatable. Some agree with you (including some very prominent people) but I don't. I think changes in the original units are usually easier to understand. But it's not an *assumption* of regression, in any case.

Comment: As I remember it, it's a good idea to standardize the predictors in order to understand what they're doing for the response. The interpretation of the parameter estimated will be clearer.

I thought they all standardized them by default, if it's wrong I'll edit my post.

Comment: No assumption at all, he asked for it though and I believe it's can be good idea to standardize (especially if you're new to regression). In the end, it comes down to the nature of whatever you're modeling.